# How to test relative positioning of elements in cypress?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cypress, assertion

I am currently new to cypress and wants to test that Forgot Password should be below Login button in Facebook page? Is there a way to do that?
[image: Facebook page]

Is there a way to test relative positioning of elements in cypress?

Comment: It is saying it does not found any element next to it.

Comment: Don't use `.next()` it only checks the HTML order, not the screen position.

Comment: okay. yeah got it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use [jQuery .position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/)

```js
cy.get('#element1')
  .then($el => $el.position().top)  // get 1st top value
  .then(top1 => {
    cy.get('#element2')
      .then($el => $el.position().top)  // get 2nd top value
      .then(top2 => {
        expect(top1).to.be.gt(top2)
      })
  })
```

**Notes**

Cypress use jQuery to find elements. Chaining `.then($el => ...` exposes the jQuery object containing the element, so now you can apply other jQuery functions that are not part of the Cypress commands.

In fact, any other Javascript functions you want.

You can also make reusable functions

```js
const getTop = ($el) = $el.position().top;

cy.get('#element1').then(getTop)  
  .then(top1 => {
    cy.get('#element2').then(getTop)
      .then(top2 => {
        expect(top1).to.be.gt(top2)
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the cypress method `next()` to determine the element next to `Log in` button like this. [next()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/next#Syntax) gets the immediately following sibling of each DOM element within a set of DOM elements.

```js
cy.get('div[type="submit"]').next().should('have.text', 'Forgot password?')
```

Comment: Does not work if css has changed element positions, for example CSS flex and grid.